# NPN BJT NOR gate to drive LED. Base resistance problem

Tags: bjt, npn, logic-level, resistor-transistor-logic

Here's a circuit I'm trying to get working :

[image]

I have two digital signals (B and C in the diagram) coming from a CD40174 flipflop.
I use these to light up two LED's.

I also use these as the input for a transistor based NOR gate the output of which I call A.

I also need to be able to drive an LED from A

The problem is that if I calculate R11 (the base resistor for the LED driving transistor) correctly (about 5K) the voltage at A is significantly less than 9V.

I am using A elsewhere and it needs to be as near 9V as possible. Also I'd like to draw as little current as possible from the flipflop outputs.

If I raise R11 to 100K I get a nicer, very nearly 9V at A, but the current through the LED (on pin 8) is significantly less than 20mA

Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Also, modern LEDs can be pretty bright with just 2 or 3 mA current. Are you for some reason stuck using these crummy old ones that need 20 mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can just connect the pin 6/7/8 transistor as an emitter follower instead of common-emitter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSVsQE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will only put ~7-8 V on the anode of the LED, so if you need this LED to be equally bright as the others in your circuit, you may have to adjust the R1 and/or R4 values down a bit.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you very much.. That looks great. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yes.. That works.. I just need to tweek the LED resistor limit values a bit. Obvious when you see it.. But as you can probably tell, I was just taking the common emitter design from somewhere else without thinking. Thanks.